# What is the best way to choose timesteps in LSTM for time series/forecasting data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm

I am developing a time-series prediction model with LSTM, as in LSTM model we need to define some [timesteps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235845/what-exactly-is-timestep-in-an-lstm-model) so that model takes into account that many numbers of the previous day's data for the future prediction and it needs to prepare train and test data accordingly as well as dimentionsof LSTM input layer.
(samples, time steps, features)

What is the optimal way to choose this timestep for any time series predictive model with LSTM?

Comment: This question is unanswerable without actually trying it out. Think of it as a hyper parameter and balance it with how performant your model needs to be.

Comment: hit and try method